# Primefaces dynamic line charts

Tags: java, charts

I'm using Primefaces 8, I am trying to generate dynamic line charts. I have a list of companies and the subscriptions they contributed each year for 5 years. I want to have the amounts on the y-axis and The years on the x-axis.

I have an unknown number of companies each time I want to create the line chart. Is there any way to dynamically create a ChartSeries for each company on the same model?

Code sample

```
    for (Company c : companies) {//list of companies from DB
        chartList1.put("2015", c.getAmount_2015());
        chartList1.put("2016", c.getAmount_2016());
        chartList1.put("2017", c.getAmount_2017());
        chartList1.put("2018", c.getAmount_2018());
        chartList1.put("2019", c.getAmount_2019());

        ChartSeries company = new ChartSeries();//I want to dynamically create this for each company
        company.setLabel(c.getCompanyName());
        company.setData(chartList1);
        model.addSeries(company);
        
    }
```

Comment: I managed to work around by creating a ChartSeries array outside the loop, the array has the size of the list of companies. I then created instances of ChartSeries which I then referenced within the loop. Like this ;                                                                                   ChartSeries[] ser = new ChartSeries[companies.size()];